# Clonezilla Live - mix command line and wizard

Tags: command-line, clonezilla, liveusb

I am running Clonezilla Live from a USB drive.

I would like to start the backup process using the wizard, then goto the command line (mounting the "partimag" folder manually) and return to the wizard finishing the backup.

How can I do this? Particularly how can I return from the command line continuing the wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not difficult if you know where to look.

Do not enter the shell to early. If Clonezilla asks for the storage device used for backups, there is a menu entry "enter_shell" in the middle of the list. If you select that one instead of a device you can enter the shell including the possibility to return to the wizards by typing the command "exit".